# parse variable in XML POST request with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, variables, soap

I'm trying to get a variable (date) into a XML post but I can't get it to work.
In the XML post I need to specify 2 dates (vndg=today and morg=today+1).

Here is my PowerShell script, it works without the date variables.

```
$vndg = (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
$morg = (Get-Date).AddDays(+1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

[XML]$SOAP = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtc xmlns="http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices">
      <caller>
        <CompanyName>companyname</CompanyName>
        <LoginName>username</LoginName>
        <Password>password</Password>
      </caller>
      <fromDateUtc>$vndg</fromDateUtc>
      <toDateUtc>$morg</toDateUtc>
    </Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtc>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
'@

$headers = @{"SOAPAction" = "http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices/Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtc"}
$destination = 'C:\Temp\GeoDynamics\Downloads\GeoPers.xml'

$URI = "https://secure.geodynamics.be/webservices/intellitracer/1.0/IntegratorWebservice.asmx?WSDL"
$out = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method Post -ContentType 'text/xml' -Body $SOAP -Headers $headers -OutFile $destination
```

Comment: `@'...'@` -> `@"..."@`

Comment: if i do that then i get an error ==> The string '25-09-2017' is not a valid AllXsd value.

Comment: i got it working by changing the format of the date variables ==> 
$vndg = (get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00")
$morg = (get-date).AddDays(+1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00")

Comment: `(Get-Date).Date.ToString('s')`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the script to the following:

```
[XML]$SOAP = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtc xmlns="http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices">
      <caller>
        <CompanyName>name</CompanyName>
        <LoginName>login</LoginName>
        <Password>password</Password>
      </caller>
      <fromDateUtc>$vndg</fromDateUtc>
      <toDateUtc>$morg</toDateUtc>
    </Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtc>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"@
```